# Why does my metaclass implementation fail with a TypeError about not being able to create NoneType instances

Tags: python, python-2.7, metaclass

I have the following Python code:

```
class MetaData(object):
    _md = {}

class _ClassMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct):
        ncls = super(_ClassMeta, cls).__new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct)
        MetaData._md[clsname] = ncls

class Meta(object):
    __metaclass__ = _ClassMeta

class Test(Meta):
    pass
```

When I try to execute it, I get this:

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    cannot create 'NoneType' instances
```

on the line with `class Test(Meta):`  I don't understand why.  The metaclass's `__new__` function evidently was called fine for the Meta class, but not for the derived Test class.

For those who ask "why" - I'm exploring runtime class registration and modification a la the ORM frameworks like Django and SqlAlchemy.  This may not be how I'll finally produce my code, but I still would like an answer to why I'm getting the TypeError exception.

Comment: First, this is Python 2.x, right? Metaclasses are one of the things that changed radically enough between 2.x and 3.x that it's worth using the specific tag…

Comment: I've added the python-2.7 tag, but in the future, you should do that yourself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is pretty simple: The [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) method has to create an instance *and return it*. You're not returning anything, so it returns `None`.

Since this is a metaclass's `__new__`, that means that it's getting called to construct the `Meta` class object. So you've just defined `Meta` as being `None`, rather than as a class of type `_ClassMeta`. Which is a perfectly valid thing to do, hence no error there, but as soon as you try to do anything with it, like `Meta()`, you'll get an exception about `NoneType` not being callable or similar.

And that includes subclassing it. You can't subclass `None`, because it's not a type.

Comment: D'oh!  The reason for the error message was because Meta is None by the time the class creation for Test occurred.  Yeah, simple, I shudder to think how long I spent staring at that, shouldn't have been more than 30 seconds.  Thanks!  I'll accept when the accept-block timer runs out